# What is the bar indicating in $\overline{z}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I was asked to solve the following question

#### prove $z=\overline{z}$

conditions : iff $z$ is real.

To begin with I have no idea what $\overline{z}$ is supposed to be what is the bar indicating here. I assumed opposite?

Can anyone give an explanation of how I might go about solving the question. And what the bar is supposed to be ?

(apologies if the question seems novice. I am not exactly a math whiz.)

Comment: complex conjugate!

Comment: One would think, if you are asked that question, then the notation $\overline{z}$ would have been explained prior to that point.

Comment: @GEdgar : Sadly, they didn't explain what it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $\bar{z}$ indicates the *complex conjugate* of $z$, which is defined as 
$$\bar{z}=a-bi,$$
where $z=a+bi$. In physics, this may be denoted $z^{*}$ instead. Note that if $z$ is real, then $b=0$ and thus
$$z=a+0i=a-0i=\bar{z}.$$
Conversely, if $z=\bar{z}$ then
$$a+bi=a-bi\Longrightarrow bi=-bi,$$
namely $b=-b$. But, this implies that $b=0$ and moreover, that $z=a+0i=a$ is real. Hence, $$z=\bar{z}\iff z\in\Bbb R.$$

---

Geometrically, one can picture the complex conjugate as an automorphic map (meaning from $\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$) [which reflects $z$ across the real axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate#/media/File:Complex_conjugate_picture.svg). With this interpretation, it makes sense that real numbers (represented as coordinates on the complex plane with a $y$ value of zero) are precisely those that equal their conjugates.

Comment: In physics, the complex conjugate may be denoted $z^*$ instead.

Answer (score 2):

If $z=a+bi$, by definition $$\overline z=a-bi$$

If $z=\overline z$, $$a+bi=a-bi\implies \color{RED}{b=0}$$

Graphically, considering $z$ as a vector on the complex plane, $\overline z$ is the reflection of $z$ along the real axis!

Brain exercise: what vectors would remain unchanged upon reflection along real axis?

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer and explanation